# CorePlot getting error on Universal library

Tags: ios, core-plot

Hi I am trying to rebuild core plot for `armv7` and `arm64` bit support, in my project. My previous version of the project was working fine with core-plot but it was 32 bit.

And for 64 bit support what I did is, download core-plot from [here](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) and open `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj` on framework folder, change architectures to `armv7` and `arm64` and valid architecture to `x86_64, i386, armv6, armv7`.

Then set Product->Scheme->Universal Library and build it.

Now I can see the library generated `build/Release-universal` with the name `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` and the header folder `CorePlotHeaders`, I copied both these to my project(the same location where the 32 bit library and header),

And then I am getting following error.

```
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3594:93: Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3594:93: Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3595:60: Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3595:93: Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3605:35: Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' from incompatible type 'NSDecimal'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3606:7: Property 'orthogonalCoordinateDecimal' not found on object of type 'CPTXYAxis *'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3608:35: Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' from incompatible type 'NSDecimal'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3620:31: Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' from incompatible type 'NSDecimal'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3634:35: Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' from incompatible type 'NSDecimal'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3635:7: Property 'orthogonalCoordinateDecimal' not found on object of type 'CPTXYAxis *'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3638:35: Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' from incompatible type 'NSDecimal'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3650:25: Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' from incompatible type 'NSDecimal'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3652:25: Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' from incompatible type 'NSDecimal'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3696:16: 'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3739:60: Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3739:93: Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3740:60: Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3740:93: Sending 'NSDecimal' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber * _Nonnull'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3750:35: Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Nullable' from incompatible type 'NSDecimal'
/Users/computer/Documents/EAP-Dec-4-2015/EAP/EAP/VALiveViewController.m:3751:7: Property 'orthogonalCoordinateDecimal' not found on object of type 'CPTXYAxis *'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Core Plot API changed slightly between 1.x and 2.x to accommodate the lack of `NSDecimal` support in Swift and to simplify it a little bit. See this [wiki page](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Core-Plot-API-Changes-Between-Versions-1.x-and-2.x) for details of the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so is it possible to build 1.x release with 64 bit support, so that I can use the library without any change in my source code.  I am using Xcode7 and IOS9 as target .

Comment: Core Plot has supported 32- and 64- bit builds on iOS since before the 1.0 release. I don't think release 1.6 will compile on Xcode 7, but you can download the pre-built release package from [GitHub](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases/tag/release_1.6).